# Why is user=<com.apple.calendarserver> giving an imap-login: Info: Disconnected (tried to use unsupported auth mechanism)?

Tags: calendar, server.app, imap

I periodically get the following lines in the log. Why is this happening? Wasn't Apple supposed to configure this for me somehow?

`Apr 04 14:40:17 imap-login: Info: Disconnected (tried to use unsupported auth mechanism): user=<com.apple.calendarserver>, method=PLAIN, rip=10.0.10.3, lip=10.0.10.3, TLS`

Can I fix it?

<sup>OS X Server 4</sup>

Comment: What version of OS X are you using on the server? You've tagged with [tag:osx-server] but that error looks like [tag:server.app]?

Comment: @grgarside It's OS X Server 4 you are right, I changed the tags.